# Pirate Roulette game winning probability followup

Tags: probability

I have seen other questions on this website asking about the probability of winning this game, but none of them has the answer I wanted.

Suppose we are playing a Pirate Roulette game with only 3 slots. I have to slide 2 swords in 2 slots. One of the three slots will make the pirate pop. Rather than choosing the slots all at once, I put the sword in the slots one by one, as how the game is played in real life. If I slide the sword into the "broken" slot, the pirate will pop. Once it pops, I lose and can't continue playing.  What is the probability that I will win?

The answer given in other threads says that it will be simply $\frac{1}{{3 \choose 2}} = \frac{1}{3}$. But shouldn't order matters since I'll be putting in the sword one by one? And since the roulette game will be over if I choose the broken slot, any combination with this slot in the first order will be counted as one combination. So if we call this broken slot slot 3, the sample space will be (1-2, 2-1, 1-3, 2-3, 3), which would make the probability of winning this game $\frac{2}{5}$.

Could someone explain why my reasoning is erroneous? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I didn't specify the rule of the game in my first post.

Comment: Can you give a link to one of the other threads?  I don't understand the rules of the game.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478468/probability-of-winning-pirate-roulette-game

Comment: Sorry - realized I didn't specify the rule of this game. I just edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample space does not consist of equiprobable cases.  The $3$ case is twice as likely.  Consider that you are equally likely to choose $1$, $2$, or $3$ for your first sword; therefore,

$$
P(3) = P(1\text{-}2)+P(1\text{-}3) = P(2\text{-}1)+P(2\text{-}3)
$$

so the desired probability is $2/6 = 1/3$ after all.

Comment: Ah I see now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, as Ross Millikan points out in his answer, $P(3)$ is conceptually equivalent to $P(3\text{-}1)+P(3\text{-}2)$; it's just that you find out you lost before you even get to either $1$ or $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that choosing $3$ first is twice the probability of the other elements in your sample space.  It corresponds to $3-1$ and $3-2$.  The $\frac 13$ answer is correct.